# How to configure maven install plugin to change project build file location

Tags: maven, installation

I have a common maven build situation in which I want to totally configure maven install behavior to my project build.

My project is typical multi module java –j2ee EAR project

The solution must work in Off-line mode, so that maven deploy and deploy-file plugins moves out from solution scope.

I tried to specify following setting in my POM but this doesn’t run with mvn –o option (offline). That means maven deploy plugin must work on-line (proxy setting) mode

```
<distributionManagement>
 <repository>
<id>Local-Build-Shared-Dir</id>
<name>My  Build Drop Folder</name>
 <url>file://X:/WorkBeanch/Maven/ProjectBuilds/.. /BuildDir/…</url>
```

…..

How I can configure maven install plugin to achieve following –

   I want to get my project build file (ear, war, or jar) in separate local folder rather than local maven repository

   I do not want any artifacts (ear, war, or jar) of my main project be placed in local maven repository. For this I tried to by-pass install build phase for other sub-module with the help of following article (install plugin + skip to true), but still install phase is executing in all sub-modules.

   I want to configure the name and build drop local folder path (name + location) for my project build file

i can achieve same by setting maven package plugin, but in this can I need to locally copying my main build file to another local folder and then clean the target folder. With this solution still I am constrained with omitting install phase i.e. running only ‘mvn –o clean package’  only.

How I can get the same set of requirement working with fine tuning maven install plugin

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the maven install plugin is to add artifacts to the local repository.

Straight from the plugin [introduction](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/):

> The Install Plugin is used during the install phase to add artifact(s)
>   to the local repository.

So you're likely going to want to not run 'mvn install', but instead run only up to the package or verify lifecycle phase.  The full lifecycle can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

On top of that, you'll likely need to write your own plugin (or use something like the maven-antrun-plugin) to copy/move the files from the target folder to wherever you want them.  Of course, this goes against the normal ideas behind maven, so you'll want to make sure you have a good reason to do something weird like that.